# Cinema Ticketing Seat ERD

Tags: erd

[image: Seat Reservation ERD]

Hi.

This is a part of my cinema ticketing system ERD and I wanted to correctly store seat into my ticket so later on when I display my seating arrangement, that particular seat shows as unavailable.

Just to note, one Hall belongs to only one cinema.

So first of all, I wanted to dynamically generate my seating arrangement so I declared a Rows table which will contain the noOfSeats that particular Row has. Because I wanted some rows to have a different number of seats, not fixed.

Then in each row, I will have many seats and I declared a Seat table to identify which seat it is in that row.

Then I included SeatID inside my ticket so it identifies which seat has been booked for a particular showtime.

and what I think is, could be a bad way to do it, when I display my seating arrangement, I identify how many rows there are in the hall, then how many seats each row has and then see if those seats have been booked for showtime by checking from my Ticket table. So if a booking exists for that seat in that showtime, it means it's unavailable.

I assume it will be a lengthy query.

I need help to check if this relationship is correct and if there are any ways to improve it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your ERD looks ok.

Depending on what is important, you can improve the ERD for faster queries, simpler queries, faster updates, less storage. But what you improve on one site, you will probably loose on the other.

What I would do to simplify the queries for available tickets: add one field to the Ticket table: available (or status). And generate a Ticket record for every seat when the Showtime record is created.
It will take a little longer to create a Showtime (and Ticket), and it will take some more space. But you will win some when querying availability.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I have done something similar for bus ticketing where I had created a ticket for every seat on the bus and when customer purchases it, the status will be changed. As you mentioned, it will take a lot of space but it was enough to find which seats are taken. Thank you again.